# "No rows to show" although it shows

Tags: overlay, ag-grid

What is the reason for that message (overlay, "No rows to show") although I get the content shown.

Code snippet:

```
this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe(projects => {
    this.rowData = projects;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your Grid is not yet ready.
Try this:

```
onGridReady(params){
 this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe(projects => {
  params.setRowData(projects);
 });
}
```